# Why does the onClick.AddListener() in Unity doesn't work while trying to loop through items in a list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, for-loop, button

I am currently trying to build a shop for my game. The inventory is a list that will be displayed on screen. As I want every item of that list to be clickable, I add a Button component as well as an *onClick.Addlistener(method)*, but see yourself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inventoryT1.Container.Count; i++)
        {

            GameObject obj = Instantiate(inventoryT1.Container[i].item.DefaultPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = GetPosition(i);
            obj.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventoryT1.Container[i].level.ToString();

            obj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadPrisonerStore(inventoryT1.Container[i-1].item); });


        }

public void LoadPrisonerStore(PrisonerObject _prisObj)
    {
        //Updating the UI
        DescriptionForMenu.text = _prisObj.description;

        //Activating/Deactivating the panels
        ShopPrisonerContainer.SetActive(false);
        PrisonerPreviewContainer.SetActive(true);
    }
```

The *inventoryT1* is a list of items and with the *AddListener*, I want to load the data of the item that is clicked on with the *LoadPrisonerStore(PrisonerObject _prisObj)* Method. The Problem that I'm having is that every Object that is created will only load data of the very last Object. Why is that and how can i fix this?

I also tried to just link the object with another Method after the *AddListener()* and this worked perfectly, but unfortunately I can't access the items data from it:

```
obj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ReturnObject(obj));
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cache the index value before using it inside the anonymous function

```
int cachedIndex = i;
obj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadPrisonerStore(inventoryT1.Container[cachedIndex -1].item); });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use while loop insted of for and write it something like this :

```
    int i = 0;
    while(i < inventoryT1.Container.Count)
        {

           int copyOfi = i;

            GameObject obj = Instantiate(inventoryT1.Container[i].item.DefaultPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = GetPosition(i);
            obj.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventoryT1.Container[i].level.ToString();

            ***obj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadPrisonerStore(inventoryT1.Container[copyOfi-1].item); });***

                 i++;
        }
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: This code will not work. It is endless loop. You don't need to change the loop type. The problem is only in `i` capturing.

Comment: @Nikolay I have done the some capturing method my making it copy of i and using the copy into delegate something like this -> *obj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadPrisonerStore(inventoryT1.Container[copyOfi-1].item); });***
I had face same issue long back in my project , changing loop to while and capturing it as above solved the issue.

Comment: I uderstnad. But it doesn't chage the fact that the code above contains infinite loop, and variable capturing in C# has nothing common with loop types.

Comment: @Nikolay Hope it works now, I have changed the code.

Comment: @OmkarP maybe it works now ... but still how is this any less complex than the original `for` loop? Why introduce an additional variable out of the scope and later potentially forget to increase it if the for loop had already covered that in a cleaner way?

Comment: caching i worked perfectly fine for me